# What is the single particle translational partition function for a single gas atom in unknown volume?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, partition-function

In the standard expression for the ideal gas translational partition function, we have a V for the volume. How do we compute this partition function for a gas when the volume is unknown, like the atmosphere? We could substitute V out using known quantities from the ideal gas law. Is this a sensible thing to do?